# How could I improve my FB Prophet forecast?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I've got 1325 days of revenue data and when plotting the components it makes 100% sense from a domain expert point of view, so the model is capturing the variations quite well (or it seems it does...). I've added the country holidays using `m.add_country_holidays(country_name='GB')`

However, when it comes to accuracy I'm getting the following averages:

```
MAPE: 0.3
MAE: 721,415
```

721,415 is not an acceptable error. Around 100K would be.

These are the MAE and MAPE plots:
[image: MAE]

[image: MAPE]

Time-series plot:
[image: time-series]

Performance metrics (first 20):

[image: performance metrics]

What else can I do to improve the accuracy of this model? Thank you

Comment: It might be helpful to outline the process you've followed so far - e.g. what are you trying to predict, any transformations applied to the target, and the model parameterisation.

Comment: I haven't applied any transformation to the target or modified any parameter. Prophet model is quite straightforward and automatic. It only needs 2 columns, date and number, which, in my case are revenue figures.

Comment: Can you include a plot of the time-series data and the predictions made by your model?

Comment: @zachdj I've added the time-series plot and performance metrics. Not sure what you mean by the predictions. The forecast table has 73 columns and won't be very readable.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  I meant a plot that includes the time series overlaid with the predictions made by FBProphet, which is what you provided

Comment: Your target looks very noisy - it seems to fluctuate between 1m and 5m. Maybe you should consider applying some sort of transformation. There also seem to be massive downward spikes (2017, 2018, 2019)... have you taken a look at these in any detail?

Comment: @bradS what kind of transformation would you suggest? Those massive downward spikes are Xmas where our revenue drops considerably. Also the 25th and 26th December we're closed therefore revenue is 0 (or at least it should be but I think there's something like 100K).

Comment: I would start with something like the log (base of your choice, 10 or `e` is common). I would also consider removing the Christmas data and treating it separately - it looks to be an outlier and is likely distorting the modelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data here is bit noisy and has a lot of fluctuations. As a few of the comments suggest, apply some transformation on it. I would say get your data in some smaller range and then apply a LSTM to predict it. I made time-series work with a LSTM with removal of noise by eliminating outliers and it worked with nice further prediction.

RNNs tend to work better with time-series data especially bidirectional-LSTM due to their backwards learning capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend DNNs for the noisy data! Actually, probably it is the worst algorithm to deal with noisy data. Here is a solution:

1. Try to smoothen your data. There are many algorithms such as Kernel ridge.
2. Reproduce the smoothen data.
3. Learn the smoothen data and predict a smoothen curve which indicates the most probable interval in which, the future values will come.